# Unable to Find the topmost view using View.rootView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, ontouchlistener, viewgroup

I have the following View structure in my activity:

- Relative Layout (id = 1)

  - Relative Layout (id = 104)

    - TextView (id = 200)

Now when TextView is touched, I want to get the topmost relative layout's id (i.e. id = 1)

I'm using setOnTouchListener and inside that, I'm writing two log statements as follows:

1. Log.d ("demo", "Inside text_view parent.parent.id: " + (v.parent.parent as ViewGroup).id)
2. Log.d ("demo", "Inside text_view rootViewID: " + (v.rootView as ViewGroup).id)

I'm able to get my topmost relative layout's id (id = 1) using 1st log statement but the second log statement is printing -1.

could someone please explain why I'm not able to get the topmost relative layout using View.rootView?

for reference: [View.rootView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getRootView())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check what view you have got exactly by below code:

```
Log.d ("tally", "Inside text_view parent: " + (v.parent).toString())
Log.d ("tally", "Inside text_view parent.parent.id: " + (v. parent.parent).toString())
```

Because, I think, `v.rootView` give you `topmost view` of `view hierarchy` .

**[UPDATE]**

**After our threads of Comment, I update here, how to track, what is exactly you got after calling `v.rootView`**

first, read another link to better understand `android's view hierarchy`

[https://medium.com/@MrAndroid/android-window-basic-concepts-a11d6fcaaf3f#:~:text=DecorView%20is%20a%20ViewGroup%20so,event%20in%20the%20dispatchTouchEvent%20method](https://medium.com/@MrAndroid/android-window-basic-concepts-a11d6fcaaf3f#:%7E:text=DecorView%20is%20a%20ViewGroup%20so,event%20in%20the%20dispatchTouchEvent%20method).

Now, let's try below things:

```
Log.d ("demo", "Inside text_view parent: " + (v.parent).toString())
Log.d ("demo", "Inside text_view parent.parent.id: " + (v.parent.parent).toString())

Log.d ("demo", "Inside text_view getRootView: " + (v.getRootView()).toString())
Log.d ("demo", "Inside text_view getRootView Name: " + (v.getRootView().accessibilityClassName).toString())
Log.d ("demo", "Inside text_view getRootView is ViewGroup: " + (v.getRootView() is ViewGroup))

if(v.getRootView() is ViewGroup){
  var vg: ViewGroup  = v.getRootView() as ViewGroup;
  trackParentView(v,0, vg)
}
```

Now, use below method `trackParentView(...)`:

```
fun trackParentView(view :View, cnt :Int, rootView :ViewGroup){
   //Log.d ("trackParentView()", "view (name) [track: "+cnt+"]: "+ view.accessibilityClassName)
   Log.d ("trackParentView()", "view (toString) [track: "+cnt+"]: "+ view.toString())
   if(view.parent != rootView){
     trackParentView(view.parent as View, cnt+1, rootView)
   } else {
     Log.d ("trackParentView()", "this is rootView at : ["+cnt+"]: "+ view.toString())
   }
 }
```

Comment: Inside text_view parent: android.widget.RelativeLayout{ace2ed7 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,300 #68} Inside text_view parent.parent.id: android.widget.RelativeLayout{d59a3c4 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,2075 #1}, I'm getting the Two Relative Layout (parent layout and parent's parent layout)

Comment: Now, check `Log.d ("tally", "Inside text_view rootViewID: " + (v.rootView).toString())`. is it give `RelativeLayout` or not?

Comment: Inside text_view rootViewID: DecorView@ca8a2ad[MainActivity], It's not giving me a RelativeLayout, but i don't understand why so and what is DecorView

Comment: Yes, my point is `v.rootView` only give you `topmost view of your view hierarchy`, so you can not use that. `DecorView` is `the root of the window's view hierarchy.` ref link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getRootView()

Comment: Oh, sorry for put wrong ref link at above comment, please see this link to understand `what is decorview`?  https://akashsaggu-55383.medium.com/overlay-using-decorview-phonewindow-f13708710475

Comment: Please see my updated answer to `track` `v.rootView` and understand `what actually you got` after call `View.rootView`.

Comment: Thanks for the info you have provided, got a lot of clarity on Android's view hierarchy. Now what I want to ask is if I have a TextView(id = 200) inside a RelativeLayout (id = 104) which itself inside a RelativeLayout (id = 1), can I get the id of my topmost relative layout (id =1) directly using the TextView or I have to do (textview.parent.parent as ViewGroup).id, because later I can have multiple numbers of relative layouts in hierarchy and a textview at last so I want to avoid doing textview.parent.parent.parent... n number of times. to get the top relative layout's id.

Comment: `can I get the id of my topmost relative layout (id =1) directly using the TextView.` Yes, for that you can use my method that describe in updated answer named `trackParentView`. For your result, just modify into my method, change condition `if(view.parent != relativeLayout)` and get `id` from that `view`.